# When will all the flowers blossom?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, problem-solving

The title is not actually correct, but I chose appeal over correctness ;)

I'd like to model a flower blossoming cycle, and these are the assumptions:

1) The instant $T$ in which each flower starts to blossom is modeled by a probability distribution $D_1$, which I assume to be $\sim N(\mu,\sigma)$;

2) Each flower has a lifespan $L$ which follows a probability distribution $D_2$, assumed for the moment to be another normal distribution $N(\lambda,\nu)$.

(The real model supposes that $D_2$ depends on the time of initial blossoming of the flower, but let's forget it for the time being.)

Question: how to find the instant(s) in time when the most flowers are blossoming together?

What I've tried so far:
Let, as stated, $T\sim N(\mu,\sigma)$ and $L\sim N(\lambda,\nu)$. Let also be $X(t)$ be the number of flowers still blossoming (i.e. alive) at time $t$.

I think it's safe to say that
\begin{equation}
P(\text{flower $F$ is alive at time $t$})=P(\text{$F$ blossomed before $t$}\ \cap \text{$F$ is not dead at time $t$})
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
P(\text{flower $F$ is alive at time $t$})=P(T\leq t\ \cap\ L\geq t-T)
\end{equation}
I assume also that the two events are independent, so that probability is just the product of the two, but I'm stuck here, since I cannot imagine a way to count those flowers.
Any hint is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there are $n$ flowers. The number of flowers still blossoming at time $t$ is a random variable $X(t)$, equal to
$$X(t)=\sum_{f=1}^n I(\text{flower $f$ is alive at time $t$})\tag1$$
where the indicator function $I(A)$ equals one if event $A$ is true, zero otherwise. The expectation of $X(t)$ is then
$$E(X(t))=n P(\text{flower $1$ is alive at time $t$})\tag2$$
since all flowers have the same blossoming behavior. If you're seeking the place where (2) is maximized as a function of $t$, you don't need to know the number of flowers; you get the same answer if you consider just one flower. Go ahead and calculate
$$P(\text{flower $1$ is alive at time $t$}) = P(T\le t\cap T+L\ge t)\tag3$$
and maximize it as a function of $t$.

Note: the assumption that the random variables $T$ and $L$ are independent does not imply that the two events on the RHS of (3) are independent. Evaluate (3) by conditioning on $T$:
$$
\begin{align}
P(T\le t\cap T+L\ge t)&=\int_{u=-\infty}^\infty P(T\le t\cap T+L\ge t\mid T=u)\,f_T(u)\,du\\
&=\int_{u=-\infty}^t P(L\ge t-u)\,f_T(u)\,du
\end{align}
$$
To compute the derivative of (3) you'll need to [differentiate under the integral sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign).

Comment: Ok, I'll work it out. My intuition tells me that the max $t$ should be given by $\mu+\lambda/2$...

Comment: I fear I need some more help... I am getting $P(T\leq t\ \cap\ T+L\geq t)=P(L\geq 0)P(T\leq t)$ by conditional probability but it cannot be right.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how to condition on $T$. However, the derivative of $X(t)$ seems non-trivial in the general case. In the special case $L$=constant, the derivative of $X(t)$ is straightforward to compute, and the maximizer is indeed $t=\mu+\lambda/2$. Maybe the same answer pops out when $L$ follows a normal distribution, but I'm not seeing it.